# Extract only if the script tag's src contains a particular word in PHP

Tags: php

I am learning PHP. I have to extract all the `script tags` of a particluar `$url` whose `src` contain a particular word say `'abc'`.

I have tried this:

```
                $domd = new DOMDocument();
                @$domd->loadHTML(@file_get_contents($url));
                $data = array();
                $items = $domd->getElementsByTagName('script');
                foreach($items as $item) {
                 if($item->hasAttribute('src')){
                    $data[] = array(
                   'src' => $item->getAttribute('src')
                  );
                 }
                }
                print_r($data);
                echo "\n";
```

The above code gives me the list of all the script tag's `src's` present in the `$url`.

But how should i check if a `src` in a script tag contains a word `'abc'` ?

Comment: I think regular expression will help. does $url containing full html code? or what is it containing?

Comment: @ripa:$url is the url of an HTML page

Comment: so you want to extract information from $data or $url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check each value in the array, to see if it contains `'abc'`, try a `foreach()` loop with an if statement using `strpos()` to see if the value contains `'abc'`, and then do something with it.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
foreach( $data as $key=>$value ) {
    if( strpos( $value['src'],'abc' ) !== false ) {
       //do something with it here
    }
}
```

Just edited this. Call the `['src']` element of the `subArray` and use that in `strpos()`. Alternately, you could change your line that builds the `$data` array to this, since you only have one element in each `subArray`:

```
if($item->hasAttribute('src')){
     $data[] = $item->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Comment: $value in my case is not a string! Getting an error as strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: What format are the elements being stored in the array? -Nevermind, just saw it's an array of arrays. So are you trying to determine if one of the elements in the subarray contains that text?